# Azure AD OpenID connection - groups not shown in token

Tags: azure, jwt, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, adal

We would like to connect our Angular frontend application to Azure AD. We started testing this with the following example project: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2018/10/24/using-adal-js-with-angular4/#

In the ‘app.module.ts’, we have provided the Azure AD config like below.

```
{
  provide: APP_CONFIG, useValue: { 
    clientId: '<our-client-id>',
    tenantId: '<our-app-id>',
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200/frameredirect',
  }
}
```

In the Azure portal we have created the app registration and configured the redirect url to match the above. According to the information mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens we should also configure the app manifest in Azure Portal, so that the user groups will be included in the token. So in the Minifest we hace set groupMembershipClaims to SecurityGroup. Now all organization groups should be included in the token. If there are to many roles, then we should see an endpoint where we can query the groups. Something like:

```
"src1" : { "endpoint" : 
"https://graph.windows.net/{tenantID}/users/{userID}/getMemberObjects" }
```

After setting up, login works. However, the user groups are not included in the access token at all. Does anyone know what we are missing?

Comment: Is the signed in user part of 6 or more groups? If yes you will get "hasgroups" claim to be "true" since your app is using oauth2AllowImplicitFlow.. Please check if you're getting "hasgroups" claim. Also, if you have a user who is part of less than 6 groups, try that to check if "groups" claim is getting included. Take a look at this link.. "groups", "hasgroups" and "groups:src1" are one after another in documentation.. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens

Comment: Hi Rohit, we do get the hasgroups: true back in the access token. But we do not get to see the groups:src1 in the access token.
All the users hthat login ave more than 6 groups.

Comment: You will NOT get back the "groups:src" claim as your app makes use of implicit grant. that's by design.. you can although use graph API to determine user's groups.. `https://graph.windows.net/{tenantID}/users/{userID}/getMemberObjects` I will add an answer and elaborate a bit with source documentation..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mention in comments, signed in user is member of more than 6 groups. In such cases you don't get back `groups` claim with all group ids, but instead Azure AD returns back an overage indicator, which is a hint to let you know that user is member of many groups. [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens)

**hasgroups claim**

In case of a SPA's that use OAuth 2.0 Implicit Grant Flow, the overage indicator used is `hasgroups` claim. The reasoning behind this is to make sure that URI fragment does not exceed beyond URL length limits. So if user is part of up to 5 groups, length is not an issue and you get back actual group IDs. In case of 6 or more, you need to make a separate call using graph API to get the groups.

[image]

**groups:src1 claim**

The `groups:src1` claim is also an overage indicator, but this one gives a little more information about which endpoint to call to get groups. I have seen this claim come through when URL length related restrictions were not applicable, e.g. if instead of Angular based SPA you were using a .NET based console application with ADAL.NET libraries for example. Again the intention is same, to let you know that user is part of many groups and you need to make a separate call to get that information.

[image]

**How to get groups related information for user?**

1. As the documentation for `hasgroups` claim itself mentions, you can make a call to Azure AD Graph API

   ```
   https://graph.windows.net/{tenantID}/users/{userID}/getMemberObjects
   ```
2. You can also use the newer Microsoft Graph API. This is newer and recommended one. You can read about comparison with Azure AD Graph API and when to use which one over here [**Microsoft Graph or Azure AD Graph**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2016/07/08/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/)

   I see that stable version v1.0 has at least two APIs that may be helpful for you:

   [**List memberOf**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0)

   ```
   GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/memberOf
   ```

   [**user:getMemberGroups**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-getmembergroups?view=graph-rest-1.0)

   ```
   POST /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/getMemberGroups
   ```

   The check for this API is transitive, unlike reading the memberOf navigation property, which returns only the groups that the user is a direct member of. It supports Office 365 and other types of groups provisioned in Azure AD. The maximum number of groups each request can return is 2046

Comment: Hi Rohit. Thanks for the explanation. We will proceed tomorrow morning with your info.

Comment: @bram how did it go? are you still facing issues getting to groups?

Comment: Hi Rohit,
we have it working with the graph api yes! thanks for the help and time!